# VSS Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback—Access Denied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, exchange-2007, vss

I'm having trouble with VSS based backups of my Exchange server. I'm getting the following error on the start of the backup:

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
. This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the writer or requestor process.


Operation:
   Gathering Writer Data


Context:
   Writer Class Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Name: System Writer
   Writer Instance ID: {6524807c-855e-4b4f-9295-dab2ac1e1948}
```

The service performing the backup is running as Local System, so I don't understand why it wouldn't have access. I've checked group policy and DCOM; there's no antivirus on the system and the firewall is disabled.

Edit:
The backup software is [CloudBerry Enterprise Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/enterprise-cloud-backup-software.aspx). I believe it uses the built-in Exchange Information Store writer, as I didn't see anything that looked like a third party writer when I ran `vssadmin list writers`. It's quite possible that I could have missed it, however.

Comment: Missing the important information - what are you using to backup? 
Some vendors use the native writers, others have their own.

Comment: I hadn't considered the possibility of a third party writer. Question updated with the name of the backup application.

Comment: Are your question version tags correct? You have tagged Exchange 2007 and Windows 2008R2. That is an unsupported combination. Exchange 2007 is only supported on Windows 2008.

Comment: Exchange 2007 service pack 3 is supported on Server 2008 R2.

Comment: My mistake - although it is only supported if you go straight to SP3. Lots of people start on RTM and wonder why it doesn't work!

Comment: What account are you running the backup under? Having reviewed the question again, my instinct is that the account you are using doesn't have the required permissions to access the writers.

Comment: It's running as local system.

Comment: You might have had another backup plan running utilizing VSS that is preventing you from accessing appropriate writer.